# Error when trying to update only one column of MySQL table using php query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update only one column of MySQL table using the code below, but for some reason it always fails and gives me **Invalid query** error! What am I doing wrong here?

```
$query = "UPDATE dbTester SET username ='$MediaUserName' WHERE ID = '".$row['ID']."'"; 
$result2 = mysql_query( $con, $query ); 
echo $query; 
if (!$result2) {
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Error:

> UPDATE dbTester SET username ='cindy' WHERE ID = '10796'Invalid query:

Comment: check the variables  also dont concat query use pdo

Comment: @Roopendra Doesn't matter

Comment: @Roopendra That won't result in an error.

Comment: @Roopendra mysql default cast

Comment: thanks all for reply. If i copy and paste same query from echo to phpmyadmin the query updates the record successfully! so what might be the problem that it doesn't work in php ?

Comment: Please read the **great big pink warning** at the [top of the manual pages](http://php.net/mysql_query) for the MySQL functions.

Comment: phili so you mean for using 2 queries in same php script i need to use mysqli_query instead of mysql_query for the second query ?

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because [`mysql_query`](http://uk.php.net/mysql_query) expects first argument to be your query in string format and an optional second argument to be connection resource.

```
resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

Comment: could you tell me why(mysqli_affected_rows($result2) == 1){ echo "success";} is not working even i know that one row is updated?

Comment: @user1788736 Because you are confusing between `mysql_*` functions and `mysqli_*` ones.

Answer (score 0):

you should use, `mysql_query($query);` instead of `mysql_query( $con, $query );`

Your syntax suits for  `mysqli_query($con, $query );`